# Ruby on Rails. Searching ActiveRecord objects where condition is the presence of one of the associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails code that queries database for employee objects, which have many `social_url_for_service` (for various services). The way it is implemented, it first gets all employees from database, and then serches for ones with Twitter. Is there any way to look for this association directly (with Employee.find() metod for example) ?

```
@e = Employee.all
@employees = []
@tweets = []
@e.each do |employee|
  if employee.social_url_for_service(:twitter)
    @employees << employee
    @tweets.concat(Twitter.user_timeline(employee.social_url_for_service(:twitter).split('/').last, count: 3))
  end
end
```

Comment: What's social_url_for_service?

Comment: sorry. It's a model method which returns url from SocialServiceLink (associated with Employee by :has_many social_service_links). SocialServiceLink model handels url storing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `social_url_for_service` is a method that grabs a `social_service_link` association with a `service_name` field:

```
Employee.joins(:social_service_links).where('social_service_links.service_name = ?', "Twitter")
```

You'll need to update this for your exact table and field names. You can also drop the `.where` call to return all employees with a service of any kind.